# mysql query get max and distinct value from table

Tags: php, mysql

this is my original table

```
+--------+-----------------------+
|cTotal  |         dateT         | 
+--------+-----------------------+
| 4      |  2015-07-21 22:41:03  | 
| 7      |  2015-08-21 01:21:12  | 
| 10     |  2015-08-21 04:35:06  | 
| 16     |  2015-09-21 12:20:05  | 
| 23     |  2015-09-21 16:51:24  | 
| 48     |  2015-10-21 02:11:08  | 
+--------+-----------------------+
```

I use STR_TO_DATE and get

```
+--------+--------------+
|cTotal  |    dateT     | 
+--------+--------------+
| 4      |  2015-07-21  | 
| 7      |  2015-08-21  | 
| 10     |  2015-08-21  | 
| 16     |  2015-09-21  | 
| 23     |  2015-09-21  | 
| 48     |  2015-10-21  | 
+--------+--------------+
```

But I want the max value of cTotal from each distinct date, something like this:

```
+--------+--------------+
|cTotal  |    dateT     | 
+--------+--------------+
| 4      |  2015-07-21  | 
| 10     |  2015-08-21  | 
| 23     |  2015-09-21  | 
| 48     |  2015-10-21  | 
+--------+--------------+
```

but I don't get the results I want.

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE( `dateT` , '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS `dateL`, `cTotal` 
FROM `pstable` 
INNER JOIN (
SELECT STR_TO_DATE( `dateT , '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS `dateL1` , MAX( `cTotal` ) AS `MaxCDay`
FROM `pstable`
GROUP BY `dateLikes`
) `grouped` 
ON `pstable`.`dateL` = `grouped`.`dateL1`
AND `pstable`.`cTotal` = `grouped`.`MaxCDay`
```

Comment: post table ddl, sample inserts and your query

Comment: my mistake, I just edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT date(dateT) as theDate, max(cTotal) as cTotal
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY date(dateT)
ORDER BY cTotal
```

Comment: lot more awesome people here than me !

Answer (score 1):

```
 select max(cTotal), DATE(dateT) from table_name group by DATE(dateT)
```

Comment: I have not voted at all, but I think the answer can be improved by explaining why this SQL statement solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on your original table:

```
select max(cTotal), dateT from table1
   group by str_to_date(dateT,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

See the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ead0f/7) demo here.